# Update automatic ListBox items when alter List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have a ListBox, I populate it with `ItemsSource` with `List<Control>`.

But when I delete or add new control for this List, I need every time reset my ListBox ItemsSource

Have any method for ListBox sync List content?

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: Also look into INotifyPropertyChanged http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: Please, can you give me a simple example for ObservableCollection contains List?

Comment: Have you tried just changing List<Control> to ObservableCollection<Control>?

Comment: @Lai32290 I posted a link to the MSDN documentation on `ObservableCollection`. Start with that.

Comment: Thank you! Simon and awhitehouse.  I had read MSDN documentation, but I had not understand how to use, so I ask here, thanks help for everybody!  My code is work with help for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `List<T>`, use an `ObservableCollection<T>`. It is a list that supports change notifications for WPF:

```
// if this isn't readonly, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and raise
// PropertyChanged when you set the property to a new instance
private readonly ObservableCollection<Control> items = 
    new ObservableCollection<Control>();

public IList<Control> Items { get { return items; } }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Xaml, use something like this...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}"/>
```

And wire it up like this...

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Control> MyItemsSource { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            MyItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Control> {new ListBox(), new TextBox()};
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

This will present the items to the ListBox.  In the example here, the collection contains a ListBox and a TextBox.  You can add/delete from the collection and get the behaviour you are after. Controls themselves are not all that great as ListBox items because they do not have a meaningful way of populating a visual.  So you will probably need to run them through an IValueConverter.

Answer (score 0):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your viewmodel.
Post that in the setter of this List, call the NotifyPropertyChanged event. This will
result in updating your changes on UI